# Tk label widget not refreshing

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter

```
from tkinter import*
hp = 10
def inc():
    global hp
    hp+=2
    mainloop()
def dec():
    global hp
    hp-=2
    mainloop()
master=Tk()
w = Label(master, text="Health = " + str(hp))
bu = Button(master, text="Increase", command=inc)
bd = Button(master, text="Decrease", command=dec)
bu.pack()
bd.pack()
w.pack()
while True:
    mainloop()
```

I want the label that displays the integer variable 'hp' to update when I click the button widget that changes its value. Why isn't it refreshing? If I put the definition bits below the tk bit, I know i'll get an error saying that the buttons' commands don't exist!

Answer (score 0):

For one, you must call `mainloop()` exactly once, and definitely not in an infinite loop.

For another, labels don't just magically update. You have to use the `config` method to change the string that is displayed in a label widget.

Answer (score 0):

The function `mainloop()` is itself a loop (the clue is in the name) so you don't call it in an infinite while loop. This will fix part of your problem.

Also, you need to use `w.config(text="somenewlabeltext")` inorder to change the text as when you originally create the label, the text is set and even when you change hp, the string does not change as you have found.

Your final code may look something like this:

```
from tkinter import *

hp = 10

def inc():
    global hp, w
    hp+=2
    w.config(text="Health = " + str(hp))

def dec():
    global hp, w
    hp-=2
    w.config(text="Health = " + str(hp))

master=Tk()

w = Label(master, text="Health = " + str(hp))
w.pack()

bu = Button(master, text="Increase", command=inc)
bu.pack()

bd = Button(master, text="Decrease", command=dec)
bd.pack()

mainloop()
```